# Get value of SQL Var conformed on varchar text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nvarchar

I have the next script example:

```
DECLARE @lCode INT
DECLARE @lText VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @lConditionName VARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @Aux VARCHAR(400)

SET @lCode = 1234;
SET @lConditionName = 'Code'

SET @Aux = '@l' + @lConditionName

SET @lText = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = ' + @Aux

PRINT @lText
```

The result is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = @lCode
```

How can i obtein the value of @Aux Var like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @lCode INT
DECLARE @lText NVARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @lConditionName NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @Aux NVARCHAR(400)

SET @lCode = 1234;
SET @lConditionName = N'Code'

SET @Aux = N'@l' + @lConditionName

SET @lText = N'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = ' + @Aux

PRINT @lText

EXEC  sp_executesql @lText, N'@lcode INT', @lcode
```

Comment: @TomasCaffrey: in SQL Server, a variable can't be named `1234`

Comment: Thank you Quassnoi. I understand but i need the value of var which name is in aux var. aux = 'lcode'... I hope to explain.

Comment: @TomasCaffrey: If you run `SELECT @Aux` it will output `"@lcode"`, is it what you want?

Comment: No, I want on `@aux` the value of `@lcode` ... on `SELECT @aux` i need 1234.

Comment: @TomasCaffrey: that's what you get with my code. Just run it and try

Comment: @TomasCaffrey: or you don't have the actual table and just need the number?

Comment: @TomasCaffrey: If so I'm afraid you can't do that in SQL Server easily. You can either write a huge `CASE` statement or pass the list of all variables AND their types to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Excelent Quassnoi, i will see how to solve. You have been very kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
DECLARE @lCode INT
DECLARE @lText NVARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @lConditionName NVARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @Aux NVARCHAR(400)

SET @lCode = 1234;
SET @lConditionName = N'Code'

SET @Aux = N'@l' + @lConditionName

SET @lText = N'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code = ' + @Aux

set @lText = N'Print ' + @Aux
print @lText
EXEC  sp_executesql @lText, N'@lcode INT', @lcode
```

**Output**

```
Print @lCode
1234
```